# the most convientent arabic fonts for web applications

Tags: asp.net

i want to know the most convenient and standardized Arabic font for web applications,,used as messages to alert the end user..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe to use fonts like Arial, Tahoma, Times New Roman as all of these support Unicode and Arabic very well. I have myself been looking and did a research & finally decided to use any of the following fonts  ***Arial, Tahoma, Times New Roman*** these are web safe fonts also. If your application is based on intranet then you can use a font of your choice if administrator is willing to install same font on all system, either you also have choice of using custom fonts by embedding. Example below is for IE

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Goudy Stout;
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url(GOUDYST0.eot);
```

CSS3 font Embedding

```
@font-face 
{  
      font-family: yourFontName ;  
      src: url( /location/of/font/FontFileName.ttf ) format("truetype");  
    }  

    /* Then use it like you would any other font */  
    .yourFontName { font-family: yourFontName , verdana, helvetica, sans-serif;  

}
```

You can read details about Font Embedding in details on internet. I have quickly put this solution together for reference.